# how to display the object value in array

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
subscription
Object {id: "3", type: "all", name: "Order Payment Status Fully Paid", category_id: "-1", admin_contact_selector: "admin-1"…}
admin_contact: Object
admin_contact_selector: "admin-1"
category: Object
display: "flight: [All]"
id: "-1"
product_type: "flight"
__proto__: Object
category_id: "-1"
id: "3"
name: "Order Payment Status Fully Paid"
type: "all"
__proto__: Object
```

I have  subscription object with the id value.
I want to display the value of display in the category object.

```
print "<pre>";
var_dump($subscription['category']['dispaly']);
print "</pre>";
?>
```

my problem return value is null,
real value is flight: [All]

Thanks a lot

Comment: you have a typo "dispaly" should be "display"

Comment: you are trying to access an object.... So you need to access it like this `echo $subscription->category->display;` If you want to access it as an array then you need to get the db results using `->result_array();` or `->row_array();` instead of using `->row()` <-- assuming ofc that you are using DB results :)

Comment: Yes bro, I using wrong spelling .

Answer (score 1):

It should be like ..

```
echo $subscription->category->display;
```

That is because you are accessing objects and you need to make use of the `->` operator. You got a `null` because of two reasons

- First, you were accessing the objects as arrays.
- Secondly, you had a typo. If eventhough it was right, that would still display `null` as your first condition fails.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of (array) variable-transfor feature provided by PHP. For example if $user is your object, then $userArray = (array) $user, $userArray will contain the array format of user object. Each property of user obect can now be accessed simply by $userArray['PROPERTYNAME']. Make sure not to use this when your object contains methods.

Comment: this is ok, but it does not apply recursively which can be a problem when working with nested objects.